# Reverse animation android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, objectanimator

How can i reverse this animation?

```
        path = new AnimatorPath();
        path.moveTo(0, 0);
        path.curveTo(-200, 200, -400, 100, -600, 50);

        anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "fabLoc", new PathEvaluator(), path.getPoints().toArray());

        anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        anim.start();
```

i tried in this way but it's not working:

```
List<PathPoint> points = new ArrayList<>(path.getPoints());
                Collections.reverse(points);

                anim = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(this, "fabLoc", new PathEvaluator(),
                        points.toArray());
```

and when i click in the button i created that should reverse the animation nothing happens

Comment: why don you use "reverse" interpolator?

Comment: something like this in lambda notation: `reverseInterpolator(t)  -> 1 - t`